# How to reduce a quadric into canonical form without rigorous calculations?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, quadratic-forms, quadrics, matrix-congruences

Consider the quadric in $(x,y,z)$ given by $x^2+y^2+z^2-2xy-2yz+2zx+x-4y+z+1=0$.I am asked to reduce it into canonical form and describe the nature.Here it is a parabolic cylinder.But the method taught to us by the college prof. is based on calculation of eigenvalues and unit eigenvectors,then applying a rotation.But this becomes very long,I am looking for a smarter approach to this problems which is based less on calculation and more on linear algebra concepts.I thought first that I can use congruence operation for this but I found that normal form under congruence is not the same as the canonical form of a quadric.

Comment: Eigenvectors and eigenvalues _are_ linear algebra concepts. There are other ways to diagonalize a quadric (eqv. diagonalize a real symmetric matrix) besides computing its eigenvalues and principal axes. Since what you really want to know is the spectrum, look into those.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first six terms can clearly be seen as the expansion of $(x-y+z)^2$, now apply completing square method.
$$(x-y+z)^2+x-4y+z+1=0$$
$$\implies (x-y+z)^2+(x-y+z)-3y+1=0$$
$$\implies \Big(x-y+z+\frac{1}{2}\Big)^2=3\Big(y-\frac{1}{4}\Big)$$
which is the required canonical form.

Comment: the planes should have been mutually perpendicular as we are rotating using orthogonal transformation.Although it is correct in the sense that we get the nature of the quadric.

Comment: I have accepted your answer but we must use orthogonal axes,here it is not so,since the planes $x-y+z+1/2=0$ and $y=1/4$ are not orthogonal.

Comment: Can you answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3439204/why-does-change-of-basis-coordinate-matrix-does-reverse-action

Comment: @KishalaySarkar, I assumed that aim of the question is to calculate the nature of the quadratic and to present it in a form from which nature is apparent, as you have emphasised in the question.

Comment: I am so sorry for that,but can you make some edit to include my actual query also?

Comment: @KishalaySarkar, I don't see any other easy method except eigen values to do an orthogonal transformation in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

Even if this is (now) an old question, for completeness I would like to give an answer.

As pointed out in the comments, rewriting the quadric as
$$\Big(x-y+z+\frac{1}{2}\Big)^2=3\Big(y-\frac{1}{4}\Big)$$
makes clear that we are dealing with a parabolic cylinder, but we want a (metric) canonical form, we have to do something more.

First, let's try to perform all the calculations.
Let $B$ be the "complete" matrix of the quadric, i.e.
$$
B=\left( \begin{matrix}1 & -1 & 1 & \frac{1}{2}\\ -1 & 1 & -1 & -2\\ 1 & -1 & 1 & \frac{1}{2}\\ \frac{1}{2} & -2 & \frac{1}{2} & 1\end{matrix} \right)
$$
and $A$ the of the "quadratic part", i.e.
$$
A=\left( \begin{matrix}1 & -1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 & -1 \\ 1 & -1 & 1 \end{matrix} \right)
$$
Since the eigenvalues of $A$ are $3$, $0$ and $0$ (I mean, $0$ has algebraic multiplicity $2$) and an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ made by corresponding eigenvectors is $\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(1,-1,1),\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1,1,0),\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}(-1,1,2)\}$, then the matrix
$$
R=\left( \begin{matrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} \\ -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & 0 & \frac{2}{\sqrt{6}} \end{matrix} \right)
$$
represents a rotation that trasform that avoid the "rectangular" term from the quadric. Indeed, if we perform the substitution
$$
\left( \begin{matrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{matrix} \right)=R\left( \begin{matrix} X \\ Y \\ Z \end{matrix} \right)
$$
we get the equation (of course, it is easy if one first notices that $x-y+z=\sqrt{3}X$)
$$
3X^2+2\sqrt{3}X-\sqrt{6}Z+1=0.
$$
Now, completing the square, we get
$$
3(X+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3})^2-\sqrt{6}(Z-\frac{2}{\sqrt{6}})=0.
$$
and then, with the obvious translation, finally
$$
3X^2-\sqrt{6}Z=0.
$$

Now, let's see if we can avoid some annoying calculations.
First of all, it's is well known that the nature of a quadric depends on the inertia of $B$ and $A$, i.e., from the number of positive, negative and zero eigenvalues of $B$ and of $A$. Inertia can be easily calculeted from Descartes' rule of signs: in this case we have for $B$ the inertia $(2,1)$ ($2$ positive eigenvalues, $1$ negative and $4-2-1=0$ equal to $0$) and for $A$, $(1,0)$, so a parabolic cylinder. Such a quadric has a canonical form like
$$
\Gamma:\ \lambda X^2+2pY=0
$$
with $\lambda$ and $p$ different from $0$ and $\lambda$ positive (the $2$ in $2p$ just serves to avoid fractions).
Indeed, if $B'$ and $A'$ are the matrix of $F$, i.e.
$$
B'=\left( \begin{matrix}\lambda & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & p\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & p & 0 & 1\end{matrix} \right)
$$
and
$$
A'=\left( \begin{matrix}\lambda & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0  \end{matrix} \right)
$$
then the inertia of $B'$ is $(2,1)$ and that of $A$ is $(1,0)$, as one expects.

We also know that there are four invariants under translation and rotation of the coordinate system, namely, if a quadric has complete matrix
$$
\mathcal{B}=\left( \begin{matrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14}\\ a_{11} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} \\ a_{13} & a_{23} & a_{33} & a_{34} \\ a_{14} & a_{24} & a_{34} & a_{44} \end{matrix} \right)
$$
then the quantities $\det(B)$, $\det(A)$, $\mathrm{tr}(A)$ and
$$
I_2=\det\left( \begin{matrix} a_{11} & a_{12}\\ a_{11} & a_{22}  \end{matrix} \right)+\det\left( \begin{matrix} a_{22} & a_{23}\\ a_{23} & a_{33}  \end{matrix} \right)+\det\left( \begin{matrix} a_{33} & a_{13}\\ a_{13} & a_{11}  \end{matrix} \right)
$$
do not change under translations and rotations.
From this, and in particular from $\mathrm{tr}(A)=\mathrm{tr}(A')$, one can easily obtain $\lambda=3$, but there is no way to get a value for $p$.

Anyway, there are also two other quantities, which, unluckily, are invariant only under rotations, but not under traslations, namely the semi-invariants
$$
\Delta_B=B_{11}+B_{22}+B_{33}
$$
(where $B_{ij}$ is the algebraic complement of the element $a_{ij}$ in $B$) and
$$
\Delta'_B=\det\left( \begin{matrix} a_{11} & a_{14}\\ a_{14} & a_{44}  \end{matrix} \right)+\det\left( \begin{matrix} a_{22} & a_{14}\\ a_{14} & a_{44}  \end{matrix} \right)+\det\left( \begin{matrix} a_{33} & a_{34}\\ a_{34} & a_{44}  \end{matrix} \right).
$$

Now, if we set $\Delta_B=\Delta_{B'}$ and $\Delta'_B=\Delta'_{B'}$, we get
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
3-p^2=-\frac{3}{2}\\
3p^2=\frac{9}{2}
\end{array}
\right.
$$
which is impossible, and so clearly **wrong**. Why?

As said, $\Delta_B$ and $\Delta'_B$ are invariants only under rotation, but to bring the quadric in canonical form, we also need a traslation. But we know that after the rotation, the quadric becomes something like $3X^2+2aX+2pY=0$, as in general we cannot avoid a linear term for $X$ (again, the $2a$ is just for convenience). Let $B''$ be the matrix for this quadric, so
$$
B''=\left( \begin{matrix}3 & 0 & 0 & a\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & p\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ a & p & 0 & 1\end{matrix} \right)
$$
then from $\Delta_B=\Delta_{B''}$ and $\Delta'_B=\Delta'_{B''}$, we get the system
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
(3-a^2)-p^2=-\frac{3}{2}\\
3p^2=\frac{9}{2}
\end{array}
\right.
$$
from which we have $p=\pm\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$: since we do not need the value of $a$, the only useful equation is $\Delta'_B=\Delta'_{B''}$.

Lastly, there is also a third possibility.
Let $\lambda^4-D_1\lambda^3+D_2\lambda^2-D_3\lambda+D_4$ the characteristic polynomial of $B$ and $\lambda^3-d_1\lambda^2+d_2\lambda-d_3$ the characteristic polynomial of $A$, **important**: the two polynomial bust be written in order to be monic.

We have the following:  if our quadric is a elliptic (possibly imaginary) or hyperbolic cylinder, then its canonical form is
$$
\lambda_1X^2+\lambda_2Y^2+\frac{D_3}{d_2}=0
$$
(where $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are the non zero eigenvalues of $A$) while if it is a parabolic cylinder, then a canonical form is
$$
\lambda_1X^2-2Y\sqrt{\frac{-D_3}{d_1}}=0
$$
With the same rationale, in the case of a pair of parallel straight lines, a canonical form is
$$
\lambda_1X^2+\frac{D_2}{d_1}=0
$$
(again, here and above, $\lambda_1$ is the non zero eigenvalue of $A$).